# Mysql sort by two columns, Val1=x, Val2

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for SQL script sort by two columns, where order=pay and clientID by ID

should display all records, the first lines should be the 'pay' and the reset by ID

```
select * 
from clients
order by order = 'pay', clientID
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, boolean expressions are treated as integers in a numeric context -- with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So, if you sort in ascending order, false shows up first.

You just need `desc`:

```
select *
from clients
order by (order = 'pay') desc, clientID;
```

Note:  `order` is a very bad name for a column because it is a reserved word and a keyword in the SQL language.  You should name it something else.  Otherwise, you have to escape the name when you type it -- and that is just a waste of effort and makes it a wee bit harder to read the query.